# Missing objects in the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have been trying to render a thumbnail for a Roblox game. I have everything ready I just need to render it. When I try to render the final product It only shows the terrain and not the actual people. I think something is wrong with the camera. Not sure though.

[image: Here is a link to show what I am talking about]

Comment: Check your outliner and make sure all the eye icons and camera icons are all turned on. Check your layers to make sure everything is visable

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: related:  [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enable all objects renderable in the outliner panel. It's the Camera button next to the object name.

Also make sure your render layer is connected to a composite output node.

Comment: Can you show me a picture of what you mean by those 2 things? I am fairly new to this so I don't know all the functions.

Comment: NVM I found out how to fix it. Thanks for your help!